# what is the best way to return a pointer to vector's data? const or non-const?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class A
{

public:
    A()
    {
        buf.push_back(65);
        buf.push_back(66);
        buf.push_back(67);
    }

    ~A(){}

    const char *  getA() const
    {
        // why never run here?
        return &buf[0];
    }

    const char * getA()
    {
        return &buf[0];
    }

    char *  getB() const
    {
        // why compile error?
        return &buf[0];
    }

    char * getB()
    {
        return &buf[0];
    }

private:
    vector<char> buf;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const char * pc = a.getA();
    const char * const cp = a.getA();
    char * p = a.getB();
}
```

two questions:

1> Why there is a compile error?

2> Why the

> const char * getA() const

never be called?(In my mind, this one should be called firstly, because I won't change the object)

I have debuged into the *vector* class implementation and found 
the

> reference operator[](size_type _Pos) const
>   {...}

was called , not the

> const_reference operator[](size_type _Pos) const{...}

one.

PS: I use VS2010.

Comment: In C++0x you can simply use the vector's `data` member function.

Comment: Alf: opposed to just doing `&v[0]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1**

There is a compiler error because you've declared `getB()` as `const`.  So therefore, `buf` is effectively `const`, so `operator[]` will return a `const` reference to the member element.

**Question 2**

That overload of `getA()` never gets called because `a` is not `const`, so the non-`const` overload takes priority.  If you do:

```
const A *p = &a;
p->getA();
```

then the `const` overload would get called.

Answer (score 1):

In a `const` member function, every member of the class is `const`. That said, you cannot return non-const pointer from a const vector, hence the error in this code:

```
char* getB() const
{
    // why compile error?
    return &buf[0];
}
```

Since inside the function, `buf` becomes `const vector<char>`, and consquently `&bug[0]` becomes `cont char*`.  So you need to make the return type as `const char*` to fix the compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:cause of "A a" was not constant , const version will never been called !

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your second question. Read this [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12).
It says that if you want your const overload to be called your object should be const too.